# Set a new layout on button

Tags: qt, layout

I have a layout (containing QLabels and QSpacers) set on a button and I want to replace this with a new one. To do this I have made the following code:

```
while(!layout.isEmpty())
{
    delete(layout.takeAt(0));
}
```

After this I set the new layout:

```
layout.addWidget(...)
layout.addSpacer(...)
...
button.setLayout(layout)
```

Unfortunately the new layout is set, but the old one can still be seen. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, you want to delete the items in the widget, not the layout.  [`QLayout::takeAt`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#takeAt) returns a `QLayoutItem*`.  Thus, you are looping through the widget's layout and deleting the layout items, but not the widgets that were added to the layout items.  As a test, you might try the following instead:

```
while(!layout.isEmpty())
{
    delete layout.itemAt(0)->widget();
    delete layout.takeAt(0);
}
```

However, this isn't what I would consider a good long-term design.  There may be a few special cases where this is the best method, but I would recommend looking into using a stacked widget or something similar to switch back and forth between the widgets presented, rather than destroy and recreate a whole array of widgets in a button.  Alternately, consider two different buttons, and destroy and reinsert just the button rather than the contents of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing

```
delete button.layout();
```

before setting the new layout.

Alternatively, you can just add the widgets etc to the existing layout (and not set a new layout then).

[Edit]
As long as you only use a pointer on the old layout, this should work:

```
QLayout* layout = button.layout();
while( !layout->isEmpty() )
{
    delete( layout->takeAt( 0 ) );
}

layout->addWidget(...)   
layout->addSpacer(...)
// do not call button.setLayout()
```

[Edit2]
If this is only an update problem you can try

```
button->update();
QApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::IgnoreUserInputEvents );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to delete the whole layout. I want to empty it and put new widgets/spacers in there. So I want to keep the same layout on the button.

Comment: Still no succes. It does show the new Layout, but the old widgets can still be seen "underneath" the new layout. It is as if deleting the layout widgets is not enough... Maybe I shouldn´t use delete, but a different command?